# Laravel - 301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-301

When I navigate to the URL `localhost/changecontrol`, I expect the `index.blade.php` to be loaded, instead I get an empty `200 OK` response after a `301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)`. The network tab shows this:

```
changecontrol -> Status Code:301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)
changecontrol/ -> 200 OK
```

The browser automatically adds the trailing slash to the URL, presumably because of the weird `301` error. I've tried different browsers and the same thing happens.

I've also tried all the usual cache clears: `route:clear`, `cache:clear`, `view:clear`.

**Route**

```
Route::namespace('ChangeControl')->group(function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'changecontrol'], function() {
        Route::get('', 'ChangeController@index');
        ...
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('changecontrol.index');
}
```

**Path to view**

```
views
    changecontrol
        index.blade.php
```

I have an identical set up for another system which uses exactly the same structure, route setup etc. and that one is working fine.

If I amend the route to `Route::get('index', 'ChangeController@index');` and then navigate to `changecontrol/index`, the view will load as expected.

So I really don't know what's going wrong? Why does it work for one system and not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - after taking a closer look at the `web.config`:

```
<match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
```

This particular rule was causing the issue, because I had a folder where it shouldn't have been:

I had a folder `public/changecontrol` (which was created mistakenly and never removed). The above rule was matching with this and that's why it was redirecting.